# @JsonSerialize / @JsonDeserialize not invoked with Spring MVC

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, jackson

I have a Spring 3.1 MVC project, and I'm having trouble deserializing a request sent to the following controller method:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/deposit",method=RequestMethod.POST)
public void deposit(@RequestBody DepositRequest request)
{
}
```

The request object which contains a Joda Money value, which I've registered a custom serializer/deserializer for:

```
public class DepositRequest {
    private Money amount;
    @JsonDeserialize(using=JodaMoneyDeserializer.class)
    @JsonSerialize(using=JodaMoneySerializer.class)
    public Money getAmount() {
        return amount;
    }
    public void setAmount(Money amount) {
        this.amount = amount;
    }
}
```

And the deserializer:

```
public class JodaMoneyDeserializer extends JsonDeserializer<Money> {

    @Override
    public Money deserialize(JsonParser parser, DeserializationContext context)
            throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {
        String text = parser.getText();
        return Money.parse(text);
    }
}
```

However, this deserializer is never invoked.  When I send the following JSON, I get a `400 - Bad Request` response, which I assume indicates that the mapper wasn't found.

```
{
    "amount" : "30AUD"
}
```

Do I need to tell Spring about this mapper somehow, or is the annotation enough?
What other steps should I be taking to get the deserialization to work?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

According to the [Javadoc of `JsonDeserialize`](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.3.0/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/annotation/JsonDeserialize.html) you should use that annotation on the setter, not the getter (while `JsonSerialize` should indeed be on the getter).

Comment: Do you have to configure the deserializer class as well ? I am attempting the same with joda-time http://stackoverflow.com/q/9484869/106261

Answer (score 7):

You could also attach your deserializer/serializer to *amount* field:

```
@JsonDeserialize(using=JodaMoneyDeserializer.class)
@JsonSerialize(using=JodaMoneySerializer.class)
private Money amount;

public Money getAmount() {
    return amount;
}

public void setAmount(Money amount) {
    this.amount = amount;
}
```

Comment: Do you understand why the `JodaMoneyDeserializer` would not be used if you specify the `as = JodaMoney.class` attribute as specified in the [documentation](http://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.4/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/annotation/JsonDeserialize.html)? I could only get it running when I use `using=` but no other attribute.

Comment: @JJD I haven't used "as" annotation before. But if I understand it correctly, "AS" is for deserializing into type you provide in annotation and "USING" is for deserializing into declared type using class specified in annotation.

Comment: Yeah, it somehow fits to what the docs tell: *"if using() is also used it has precedence [...] and value of this annotation property is ignored"*. Although, I cannot confirm that `as =` is ignored - it did not work at all for me when I specified both at the same time.