# I have a string : "14 Feb 2012" that I want to deserialize to a joda-time LocalDate via spring/json/jackson

Tags: json, spring, spring-mvc

How do I create my own json mapping serialization/desrialization ?

Using spring 3.1 annotions.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/Save", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String saveDTO(@Valid @RequestBody final myDTO myDTO,Model model){
```

where myDTO contains a LocalDate, and I have correctly created the json using jquery/javascript, the error message is so :

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid format: "14-Feb-2012" is malformed 
at "-Feb-2012" at org.joda.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.parseDateTime(DateTimeFormatter.java:866)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try adding `@DateTimeFormat` annotation to `LocalDate` with this date format `dd-MMM-yyyy` i.e.

```
@DateTimeFormat(pattern = "dd-MMM-yyyy")
Date LocalDate;
```